# No me muestra la imagen al poner la ruta en <img src="rutaImg"> - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, razor

Cuando pongo la ruta de la imagen en la celda

```
<th><img class="mt-5" src="@Url.Content(item.UrlImagen)" width="80" height="80"/></th>
```

no se me visualiza la imagen.

La ruta de la imagen en MySql esta en la carpeta `principal\imagenes\`.

Tal vez no encuentra la carpeta en mi proyecto, aclaro que estoy usando **ASP.NET MVC Razor**. La carpeta "principal" esta adentro de la carpeta "Home", al mismo nivel donde estan los `.cshtml`, que debería hacer para solucionarlo?

```html
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "caca";

    Autor autor = new Autor();
    Categoria category = new Categoria();
    Editorial editorial = new Editorial();

    N_Libro nb = new N_Libro();
    N_Autor na = new N_Autor();
    N_Editorial de = new N_Editorial();
    N_Categoria nc = new N_Categoria();

    List<Libro> listBooks = new List<Libro>();
    listBooks = nb.listaLibros();

}

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-primary mt-5 border-primary" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>   
                <th>Nombre</th> 
                <th>Autor</th>  
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (Libro item in listBooks)
             {
                autor = na.getAutor(item.IdAutor);
                editorial = de.getEditorial(item.IdEditorial);
                category = nc.getCategoria(item.IdCategoria);
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Baja</button>
                    </th>
                    <th>@item.Nombre</th>
                    <th>@autor.Nombre</th> 
                    <th class="col-md-3">@item.Descripcion</th>
                    <th>@item.Precio</th>
                    <th><img class="mt-5" src="@Url.Content(item.UrlImagen)" width="80" height="80"/></th>  
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, por que tienes la carpeta de la Imágenes dentro de la carpeta de las Vistas?. Eso va en contra de la estructura MVC del proyecto.

Comment: Indica por favor también como tienes almacenado el **path** de las imágenes, o sea, lo que contiene `item.UrlImagen`.

Comment: Gracias por contestar!,me olvide de aclarar que Soy nuevo usando MVC, en donde debería poner la carpeta imágenes en mi proyecto MVC? el path de item.UrlImagen es: principal\imagenes\libro4.jpg

Comment: Toma: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY es un workshop que hice junto con la comunidad de SOes hace un tiempo, fue un resumen de cursos de alrededor de 30 horas que llevé en la Microsoft Virtual Academy (cuando todavía existía)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO!** en primer lugar saque la carpeta "principal" de la carpeta Home, y la coloqué en la raíz del proyecto como corresponde. Faltaba poner la barra "/" al principio de la ruta de la imagen. A continuación muestro la forma correcta:

```
<img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\","/")" width="80" height="80" /></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

En principio deberías cambiar de sitio la carpeta donde almacenas la imágenes en el proyecto ASP.NET MVC. Lo correcto sería colocarlas dentro de una carpeta en el **directorio raiz** del proyecto.

Por otra parte, para que te funcione el ejemplo tal y como lo tienes, debes resolver el **Path** de la imagen, **desde el directorio raíz del proyecto** con el caracter "**~**" (ALT + 126).

En tu caso, si las imágenes están dentro del directorio **`Views\Home\`**, el código sería así:

```
src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/" + item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\","/"))"
```

Como ves, también se ha sustituido la **barra invertida** del **Path** de la imagen "**`\`**", por la barra de Url "**`/`**".

Comment: Gracias! copie lo que hiciste, pero sigue sin mostrarme la imagen!

Comment: @Claudio Donde tienes exáctamente la imagen. Indícame la ruta completa en relación al proyecto. Con lo que te he contestado debe funcionar perfectamente.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102356/discussion-on-answer-by-rafael-acosta-no-me-muestra-la-imagen-al-poner-la-ruta-e).